# Pandas udf on multiple columns, pandas applay analogue in pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe SDF: id_1, id_2, col1, ..., col60, for example. id_1, id_2 set is unique key.

I want to apply some model to whole row like in pandas.DataFrame.apply without groupping:
SDF['new col'] = model.predict(SDF[col1, ..., col60])

I've tried pandas_udf with SCALAR or GROUPED_MAP in withColumn(), but it didn't go well.

How should i perform that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a udf and use that with the `withColumn`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def predictor(col1, col2):
    val = model.predict([[col1, col2]])
    return float(val[0])
udf_predictor = F.udf(predictor, FloatType())

SDF= df.withColumn("new_col", udf_predictor(col1, col2))
```

Comment: can I use pandas_udf somehow or it's overkill?
and how pass more than two columns (a list of columns) in your solution?

Comment: I don't think it is needed here. Regarding more columns you can add them into the list [[col1, col2, col3, col4, .......]]